# Compare list of list with dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My list of list is

```
candidates= [[714, 1023, 768, 1078], [803, 938, 868, 995]]
```

My dictionary is:

```
main_dict = {(1561, 48, 1623, 105): [[[1592, 58]],
                                     [[1591, 59]],
                                     [[1585, 59]],
                                     [[1600, 58]]],

             (714, 1023, 768, 1078): [[[1, 5]],
                                      [[2, 6]],
                                      [[3, 3]],
                                      [[4, 3]]],

             (803, 938, 868, 995): [[[14, 5]],
                                    [[22, 64]],
                                    [[34, 31]],
                                    [[43, 32]]]

             }
```

I would like to have 2 lists, `candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key` which contains the corresponding `values` of `candidates` that exist in `main_dict`, and the other list contains the `values` that are in `main_dict` but not in `candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key`.

Here is what I tried, very cluttering and slow. Can someone have a faster way? Furthermore, how can I have an else statement that has the list of keys `v` which do not exist in `candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key` but in `main_dict`?

It is guaranteed that the `candidates` values will always be in the `main_dict` keys, and in the same order of appearance as the `candidates`.

```
candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key = []

values_of_main_dict_not_in_candidates_values_list=[] 

for x in candidates:
    for k, v in main_dict.items():
        if x == list(k):
            candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key.append(v)
```

Comment: From the dictionary, create a list of all keys. Then two difference conditions. First would be `x = list(set(list1).symmetric_difference(list2))` and `y = list(set(list2).symmetric_difference(list1))` That will give you the list of keys you need. Then search thru the main_dict to get each set of values. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a normal list comprehension with dict lookup would do fine. There isn't any need for nested loops

```
candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key = [main_dict[tuple(c)] for c in candidates]

values_of_main_dict_not_in_candidates_values_list = [v for k,v in main_dict.items() if list(k) not in candidates]
```

Comment: how about `values_of_main_dict_not_in_candidates_values_list`

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to output a list of values that are *not* in the candidates in addition to a list of those that are, you are going to have to iterate through the dictionary in one form or another in any case.

Therefore the code in the question is basically fine. But you could improve it slightly by using a set of the candidates (converted to the tuples used as dictionary keys) to test inclusion, rather than having nested loops.  Because you know that these are used as dictionary keys, you also know that they can be used as elements of a set.

```
candidate_tuples = set(map(tuple, candidates))

candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key = []
values_of_main_dict_not_in_candidates_values_list = [] 

for k, v in main_dict.items():
    if k in candidate_tuples:
        candidate_values_exists_in_dict_key.append(v)
    else:
        values_of_main_dict_not_in_candidates_values_list.append(v)
```